# Can someone fill in the gaps in layman's terms on the connection between $dN_p$, endomorphisms and quadratic forms?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, differential-geometry

I am transcribing what is explained [in this part of a lecture on the tangent space](https://youtu.be/VELPA0I5MGg?t=3065):

1. The differential of the Gauss map $dN_p: T_pS \to T_pS$ is an endomorphism of the vector space $T_pS.$ Check! Clear as can be.
2. Theorem: $dN_p$ is a symmetric endomorphism of $T_pS:$

$$\langle dN_p(v),w\rangle=\langle v, dN_p(w)\rangle, \forall v,w \in T_pS$$

I don't doubt this is true, but why is the scalar product between the differential of the normal to a surface and a vector in the tangent space at a point suddenly introduced. I understand there doesn't have to be a reason, but **what is the natural application or mathematical need for this operation**, again, regardless of the fact that it is true?

3. "When a mathematician has a symmetric endomorphism of a vector space he or she looks at the associated quadratic form." Here he defines the second fundamental form $II_p: T_pS\times T_pS\to \mathbb R; v,w\mapsto -\langle dN_p(v),w\rangle.$

**What is the motivation or natural application of this operation, and why is it so much of a given that it is an operation of interest?**

Comment: it is used to calculate the curvature of the surface $S$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You already got it, check.
2. If you already have an endomorphism $-{\rm d}N_p$, it is natural to check whether it is self-adjoint or not. And since $v \in T_pS$ implies ${\rm d}N_p(v) \in T_pS$ as well, it makes sense to look at $\langle {\rm d}N_p(v),w\rangle$ for $w \in T_pS$. This is the product between two tangent vectors to $S$ at a given point, it makes perfect sense. And why do you want to see whether ${\rm d}N_p$ is self-adjoint? Because if it is, then it is diagonalizable in some orthonormal basis for $T_pS$, which is great: you should expect geometric meaning for the eigenvalues (principal curvatures) and eigenvectors (principal directions). Check.
3. The second fundamental form ${\rm II}$ is perhaps more natural in the Riemannian geometry setting, but the idea is like this: take a curve $c:(-\epsilon,\epsilon) \to S$ with $c(0) = p$. You know that $c'(0)$ is tangent to $S$ at $p$, but $c''(0)$ might not be. We write $(Dc'/{\rm d}t)(0)$ for the tangent component of $c''(0)$. And what about the normal part? It is a multiple of the unit normal $N(p)$. What is the multiple? It is $\langle -{\rm d}N_p(c'(0)), c'(0)\rangle$ (this is linear algebra). Since every tangent vector to $S$ at $p$ is $c'(0)$ for some $c$ as above, it makes sense to abstract this a bit and consider the quadratic form $T_pS \ni v \mapsto \langle -{\rm d}N_p(v),v\rangle \in \Bbb R$. To study this better, polarize it to obtain a symmetric bilinear form. It is precisely the Second Fundamental Form ${\rm II}$. Check.